# Cannot align rows and columns correctly when reading a CSV file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

By using pandas library, I want to generate a spreadsheet format from CSV. but when I use the below codes, the alignment for rows and columns cannot be connected.

I doubted about the text code format(such as ANSI..) but it would not be.

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\yeong\\Desktop\\Data analyst\\interest-rates.csv')

data.head()

Country or currency union;Central bank interest rate (%);Date of last change
0                                                    Albania;1.05;4 May 2016
1                                                   Angola;16.0;30 June 2016
2                                              Argentina;26.25;11 April 2017
3                                               Armenia;6.0;14 February 2017
4                                                Australia;1.5;2 August 2016
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the delimiter in order to parse the table correctly. It states in the `read_csv` function that `sep : str, default ‘,’`. Code by default is looking for commas to separate out the data. Change it to the semi-colon and it should work.

```
import pandas as pd

%matplotlib inline

data = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\yeong\Desktop\Data analyst\interest-rates.csv',sep=';')

data.head()
```